# Making a GUI without a framework in C

Tags: c, user-interface, frameworks

I'm learning C (I just finished Chapter 2 or Unit 2) of the C Programming Language, I skimmed to the end and saw that at no point anything was said about how to create a GUI, and from what I've looked up, it seems I have to use a framework, but I hate the idea of that. How would I create a GUI without a framework? How exactly do these frameworks work and what language are they written in? I'm not making a massive application, even if it takes me a week, would it be feasible to write a GUI application (in C) to do something simple like creating a window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build your own framework based on OpenGL or Xlib. Or use good graphics library like [Motif](http://www.opengroup.org/motif/) or [CGUI](http://cgui.sourceforge.net/). Or use something awful like GTK.

Comment: why do you like cgui and motif and what is your gripe with gtk? isn't firefox made with gtk?

Comment: @David, GTK is awful library: not only by exterior but by its inner structure (a glib-based structures is a real nightmare, it's almost like Qt)!

Answer (score 4):

Not the best road to take. I would suggest a cross platform library, like [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/).

Comment: Okay so how do I use GtK? I know how to use winapi (c#.. .net framework, etc) but how do I use GTK? –

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, no go.

C can't do anything except manage memory and possibly do software interrupts (if you do pointer hacking).

You need a library to do anything.

GUI is very complex, you can't do anything "simple" with it. It's a problem I face every single day.

If you want a window in C, you need X11, GTK, Windows API, Video hacking, or other fun stuff.

Oh, and Video hacking is a no go, OS will throw an exception if you even try to touch video memory without its permission.

Oh, and the "simple button" you speak of, in Windows API is actually a Window itself, not very simple.

Comment: "OS will throw an exception if you even try to touch video memory without its permission." - it's rather that userland processes have access to virtual memory, so treating addresses as physical addresses won't work.

Comment: Okay so how do I use GtK? I know how to use winapi (c#.. .net framework, etc) but how do I use GTK?

Comment: The tutorials for setting up GTK on Debian based systems is very very simple. the compilation requires "gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`" or something along those lines. with apt-get you can set up gtk in mere minutes. Although, good luck using it elsewhere. It took me several days to set up on Windows. And I haven't really used many unix based systems other than Ubuntu and Fedora (on which I have never used gtk).

Comment: I'm currently using fedora lxde spin for development and fedora gnome for desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a basic framework using the WINAPI

[There is a great tutorial here.](http://www.zetcode.com/gui/winapi/)

The problem with using C and primitive frameworks like WINAPI is that manging layout and state becomes exceedingly difficult.

If you targeting a normal operating system, the `C` only requirement becomes unreasonable. I recommend you go with `C++` and `Qt` and compile your `C` code in a `C++` compiler.

Comment: Sorry, but any WINAPI stuff is a no-go, this needs to be cross-platform, I'm a linux user.

Comment: @David probably should have said that before :-)