# Blocking read() and write() on multiple threads in Linux

Tags: linux, asynchronous, blocking

I have a Linux process that needs to read from, say, the keyboard and mouse.  It needs to do this asynchronously while also doing some main process.

The implementation I've come up with is to have the main process in one thread, and have two separate threads always read()ing from the keyboard and mouse.  If Linux read() is blocking, will the keyboard and mouse threads become blocked while the main thread continues executing (what I want), or will the entire process become blocked?

Comment: There is no reason the other threads should block.  Alternatively you might be able get away with just using `select` with timeout, occassionally poll your input while otherwise process whatever main does.

Comment: Threading is one way; [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) is another.

Comment: You should prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to `select` (google for `C10K problem`), and you want to implement an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)

Comment: It is curious that you are `read(2)`-ing the mouse and the keyboard.... Generally, the X11 server is reading them.

Comment: Prefer epoll() as it is meant to replace select and poll system calls.  On the other part regarding blocking, a block on one thread will not block other threads of the same process.

Answer (score 3):

All threads in a process will not block as a result of one or more threads in the process becoming blocked.  Each thread will be scheduled if it is able to run, within the rules of the scheduler in effect.

So your design is quite valid.  Just use proper synchronization techniques if the data you read has to be consumed by another thread.  Semaphores and message queues are handy for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use several threads, as [answered by Amardeep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23451974/841108), then you need synchronization techniques (perhaps Pthread [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) and mutexes). Then read a [tutorial about pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

Notice that for real keyboard input in a terminal you may want to use libraries like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (they permit more editing than the classical [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or `fgets` approach; read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page).

You could also have an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582916/841108). Then you could (or not) have a single thread.

You could also want a graphical user interface (i.e. windows, buttons, etc...), then you want to use a library like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [Gtk](http://gtk.org/) or [libsdl](http://www.libsdl.org/) etc which provides a powerful event loop. (Don't dare doing low-level [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) programming directly, [life is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23445723/841108) for [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241155/making-a-gui-without-a-framework-in-c)).

You may want to do [non-blocking IO](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html) (which is handy in event loops), set up with [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) `F_SETFL` the `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

You could do Posix asynchronous IO, see [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html).

You may want to be notified that IO is possible thru the `SIGIO` [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (but use signals with care, often a signal handler just sets up a `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable tested elsewhere!), use `fcntl` with `F_SETOWN` (on the result of [`getpid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html)) and `O_ASYNC`

You could also make your application a specialized Web server, by using an HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)